# How can i wait until the rotation speed of a object is getting to some value then to slow down?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpinObject : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float rotationMultiplier;
    public GameObject[] objectsToRotate;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Length; i++)
        {
            rotationMultiplier += 0.1f;
            objectsToRotate[i].transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Time.deltaTime * rotationMultiplier);
        }
    }
}
```

With this line i speed up the rotation slowly:

```
rotationMultiplier += 0.1f;
```

Now i want to add a IF condition so if rotationMultiplier get to for example speed 500 then start slow down like:

rotationMultiplier -= 0.1f;

The problem is that rotationMultiplier is a float so i can't just check IF rotationMultiplier == 500

Comment: Why can't you just do 500.0f?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a boolean to check whether you must accelerate or decelerate

```
private bool slowDown = false;

for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Length; i++)
{
    if( rotationMultiplier > 500)
        slowDown = true ;
    else if( rotationMultiplier < 0 )
        slowDown = false;

    rotationMultiplier = (slowDown) ? rotationMultiplier - 0.1f : rotationMultiplier + 0.1f;
    objectsToRotate[i].transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Time.deltaTime * rotationMultiplier);
}
```

Otherwise, you could use [`Mathf.PingPong`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PingPong.html) maybe :

```
for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Length; i++)
{
    rotationMultiplier = Mathf.PingPong( Time.time, 500 ) ;
    objectsToRotate[i].transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Time.deltaTime * rotationMultiplier);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bool to determine your state (Speed up or slow down)

```
public bool isIncreasing;


if(rotationMultiplier >= 500)
{
   isIncreasing=false;
}
if(rotationMultiplier <= 0) //or your desired value
{
   isIncreasing=true;
}


if(isIncreasing)
{
 //do your speed up here
}

else
{
 //do your slow down here
}
```

Comment: While i was typing this @Hellium also answered similar one

Answer (score 0):

You can convert float to int then can check

```
for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Length; i++)
{
   if(rotationMultiplier >= 500)
   {
      rotationMultiplier -= 0.1f;
   }
   else
   {
     rotationMultiplier += 0.1f;
   }
   objectsToRotate[i].transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Time.deltaTime * rotationMultiplier);
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution. But instead to get to 500 it's getting only to 499.0215 so it's never slow down.

Comment: Do you need to check it as INT ? @danielllee

Comment: With this solution, the value of `rotationMultiplier` will oscillate between 500 and 499.xxx indefinitely